# Slot triggers its own signal

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I'm trying to setup a `QTableWidget` that colours cells in red after a user has changed them.

```
table.itemChanged.connect(flag_cell_unsaved)

@pyqtSlot(QtGui.QTableWidgetItem)
def flag_cell_unsaved(item):
    item.setForeground(Qt.red)
```

However, changing the item text to red causes the emission of another `itemChanged` signal.

I can hack around by disconnecting the signal during the slot function, but I feel like there should be a better/simple way to handle this.

Comment: given you are connecting `self.flag_cell_unsaved` shouldn't the method signature be `def flag_cell_unsaved(self, item):`?

Comment: Ah yep, edited to remove the unnecessary class references

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's correct behavior: your item did change, after all. It's not a problem as long as you won't modify the item unnecessarily:

```
@pyqtSlot(QtGui.QTableWidgetItem)
def flag_cell_unsaved(self, item):
    if item.foreground() != Qt.red:
        item.setForeground(Qt.red)
```

Comment: Yeah agreed, cheers for the approach! Building on this, I think another good solution would be to sub-class the QTable and filter the signal to more specific behavior (but I can't be bothered for this application!)

Comment: @kwekL The signal must be emitted every time the value changes. If it's not, you've broken the basic contract that every `QAbstractItemModel` must fulfill, and you're on your own. Things might work, or they might not, or your hard drive might get formatted :)

Answer (score 2):

Use [blockSignals](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#blockSignals) for the QObject that emits the signal:

```
QTableWidgetNAME.blockSignals(True)
item.setForeground(Qt.red)
QTableWidgetNAME.blockSignals(False)
```

Comment: Blocking the signal is incorrect and breaks the semantics of the model. It's not the right approach.

Comment: Blocking signals is a pretty common approach.  I use it in global refresh functions all the time.

Comment: I agree that is a subtle code smell / this leads to issues such as those described in Brendan's answer. Still, a useful feature I didn't know about.

Answer (score 1):

Adding on to [Zlatomir's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36420579/1547004) answer, it can be helpful to wrap this in a context manager to prevent it from unintentionally silencing all signals in case an exception happens to occur between the `blockSignals` calls.  It also allows you to have nested operations that require the signals to be blocked and makes sure signals aren't re-enabled in the middle of a nested block.

```
import contextlib

@contextlib.contextmanager
def block_signals(obj):
    orig = obj.signalsBlocked()
    obj.blockSignals(True)
    yield obj
    obj.blockSignals(orig)

...

with block_signals(table_widget):
    item.setForeground(Qt.red)
    with block_signals(table_widget):
        pass
    # Signals are still blocked here.
```